# I install webpack and cli webpack but got error and idk why

Tags: webpack

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-cli--save-dev - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'webpack-cli--save-dev@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-10-26T01_23_29_577Z-debug-0.log

I try to install each but can install only webpack but webpack cli cannot

Answer (score 0):

What command did you use to install webpack-cli?

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
```

You probably made a typo, try copy pasting this command to install webpack-cli